# Why Head-up Notifications don't be shown if app is not running

Tags: android, notifications

I implemented Head-up Notifications with fcm.
When app receive fcm notification, Head-up notification show up on screen if my app is running. That's good.

But if my app is background or killed, Head-up notification don't be shown.
How can I solve this problem?
(Maybe I think if my app is running when fcm notification received, MyFirebaseMessagingService work good. But if my app is background or killed, MyFirebaseMessagingService class don't work)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage message) {

        Intent push = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        push.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, push, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setVibrate(new long[] {0})
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager nm =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(1, builder.build());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of FCM messages are available.

1. Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
2. Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

**Notification messages won't show. when your app is not running or killed.**

Please check the below link, it will help you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options