# Firebase push notifications vibrate in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1` for Android and **trying to make the device vibrate while application is in background and a push notification is received.**
I send following json to FCM server:

```
to: 'topics/...',
notification: {
    title: 'New Message',
    body: 'top security body',
    sound: 'mysound',
    action_click: 'top_security'
}
```

When the app is in foreground, the `onMessageReceived` method of `FirebaseMessagingService` is triggered and I can add vibration. But, when the app is in background, `onMessageReceived` is not called and I have no control on the vibration. My first thought was to use `data` block instead both for background and foreground, but iOS client does not receive pushes in background if there is no `notification` block.

So how can I add vibration to push notification when the app is in background?
P.S. When I turn on vibrate mode on the device, the push notification cause vibrating instead of playing the sound.

Comment: because you should send silent notification , follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570200/firebase-silent-apns-notification)

Comment: Please refer my answer in this link, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42505362/1404798

Comment: @mahmoudmoustafa I'm using android, see tags

Comment: See also this answer and [this answer](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/27)
 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446300/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-vibration)

Answer (score 2):

Use `data` payload instead of `notification` payload because data payload will trigger `onMessageReceived` even though the app is background or foreground. Your request will look like this

```
data: {
    title: 'New Message',
    body: 'top security body',
    sound: 'mysound',
    action_click: 'top_security'
}
```

To retrieve the data from `data` payload inside `onMessageReceived`, call `remoteMessage.getData();` which will return the result in a `Map<String,String>`

For example:

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
String title = data.get("title");
String body = data.get("body");
```

Then customize the notification as you want with that data.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: We use push notifications both for android and ios. iOS client does not show push notification in background if there is no `notification` block.

Comment: You are also able to combine both of the payloads (notification and data) in one request. Have you tried it? @IlyaEremin